# Sharing internet connection over Bluetooth from Desktop to Android

Tags: 12.04, internet, android, bluetooth

What I have is these

1. Desktop PC **without** a wifi adapter
2. Bluetooth dongle
3. Android phone

What I want is

- Sharing the internet connection on Desktop with the phone.

Although it has been asked on the forum but it was for Nokia phones. Kindly tell me what to do stepwise as I am quite new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

There is an option in the Windows smartphones since 5.1 edition of Windows mobile, that allows you to use your Desktop or laptop's Internet via USB, but can't able to find this option in Android (without wifi), of course you can use via wifi, but I am looking for similar sort of option either blue-tooth or USB means.

It is possible I believe so. Lets see , I am looking forward, fingers crossed. :)